# Number of ways to form a 3-letter word with repetition allowed?

Tags: combinatorics

The additional rule is: no letter can be used more often than it appears in MILLENNIUM? (Which is pretty logical I guess)

MILLENNIUM = MM, II, LL, NN, E, U

My logic:

**Case 1:** Double letters + 1 distinct letters (choose pair from M, I, L, N + 1 from E, U)

$$\dbinom{4}{1} \dbinom{2}{1} \frac{3!}{2!} = 24$$

**Case 2:** All 3 distinct letters (permute 3 from M,I,L,E,N,U)

$$_6P_3 = 120$$

Sum = 24 + 120 = 144

Part (b): What about a four-letter word?

My logic:

**Case 1:** Double letters + Double letters (choose two from M, I, L, N)

$$\dbinom{4}{2} \frac{4!}{2! 2!} = 36$$

**Case 2:** Double letters + 2 distinct letters (choose 1 from M, I, L, N)

$$\dbinom{4}{1} \frac{4!}{2!} = 48$$

**Case 3:** All 4 distinct letters (permute 4 from M,I,L,E,N,U)

$$_6P_4 = 360$$

Sum = 36+48+360 = 444

However my answer is incorrect for both. Is there a mistake I made somewhere?

Comment: The problem seems to be that when you are looking at the case involving double letters, you are excluding possibilities like "MMI."

Comment: I think I get it. Part (a) case 1:$$\dbinom{4}{1} \dbinom{5}{1} \frac{3!}{2!} = 60$$

Comment: @B.A. Were you able to fix part b) as well? For part b) your case 1 and case 3 are okay. It is case 2 that is the problem.

Comment: Part(b) case 2: 
$$\dbinom{4}{1} \dbinom{5}{2} \frac{4!}{2!} = 480$$

Comment: @B.A. That looks good to me.

Comment: @Braindead just post an "answer" and let me mark it as correct already :)

Comment: @Braindead: You are right, I need coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both parts, the problem is with case 2 with one double letter: The letters MM, II, LL, NN are being prevented from being used as a single.

As B.A. noted in the comments Part a) Case 2 should be

$$\displaystyle\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{1}\dfrac{3!}{2!},$$

and Part b) Case 2 should be:

$$\displaystyle\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2}\dfrac{4!}{2!}$$

Answer (score 0):

MILLENNIUM is composed of 6 symbols with 4 of them having multiplicity of 2 $=\{M^2, I^2, L^2, N^2, E^1, U^1\}$

(A) 3 Letter 'words':

Using X,Y,Z as placeholders, these will be permutations of either XXY or XYZ (a double and single, or three singles). In the first case, choose X from M,I,L,N, and Y from the 5 remaining letters.  In the second case choose all 3 different letters from M,I,L,N,E,U.
 $$\text{Count} =\,^3P_{2,1}\,^4C_1\,^5C_1+\,^3P_{1,1,1}\,^6C_3 \\= \frac{3!}{2!\,1!}\frac{4!}{1!\,3!}\frac{5!}{1!\,4!}+\frac{3!}{1!\,1!\,1!}\frac{6!}{3!\,3!} \\= 60+120=180$$

(A) 4 Letter 'words':

Using W,X,Y,Z as placeholders, these will be permutations of either WWXX, WWXY, WXYZ, with the placeholders filled as above.

$$\text{Count} =\,^4P_{2,2}\,^4C_2 + \,^4P_{2,1,1}\,^4C_1\,^5C_2 +\,^4P_{1,1,1,1}\,^6C_4 \\= \frac{4!}{2!\,2!}\frac{4!}{2!\,2!}+\frac{4!}{2!\,1!\,1!}\frac{4!}{1!\,3!}\frac{5!}{2!\,3!} + \frac{4!}{1!\,1!\,1!\,1!}\frac{6!}{4!\,2!} \\= 36 + 480 + 360\\= 876$$

Answer (score 0):

To find the number of different ways to spell any word is simply counting up all the letters of that word, taking that total in factorial and dividing it by the factorial of all the duplicate letters. Ex. "Millennium" - 10!/(2!*2!*2!*2!)